# How do I persist a value in ASP.Net MVC 3 without a post?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, viewstate

I need to do something like the following:

1. On the page, when a checkbox state is changed, do an jQuery AJAX call to the server to set the state of the checkbox.
2. Refresh a jqGrid which will use this value (another AJAX call).

There is no post.

In ASP.Net, I would set the value in the viewstate and use it from there.  However, viewstate is not valid in MVC.

Where can I store this value so it will be available on all subsequent calls to this page for this session?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "available on all subsequent calls to this page for this session".  What is a "call to this page"?

Comment: Any other post that may occur.

Comment: I don't really understand the issue.  The whole point of sending the checkbox state to the server is so that it's stored on the server.  Any subsequent calls will know what the new state is.

Comment: If I were using a typical post, then sure, it would work fine.  But I'm sending it via jQuery AJAX, therefore there is no post.  Sure, MVC does some magic to make it appear as though the values state are stored on the server, but they are not.  The values are passed in from the post each time a post is sent.  This is why your entire session can be disposed and re-created, but it appears that your values are still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the box still checked? Just reuse the value from the client.  If you're replacing it when you get the result via AJAX, you should be setting the value in the model before the (AJAX) response is returned so it has the proper value on the client.  If the box represents some sort of preference, chosen once then applicable across all pages, then store it in the session or in some persistence mechanism (cookie, SQL server DB, RavenDB), retrieving it from there as needed.

Comment: But the problem here is that I need to access the state of the checkbox on the server, not the client.

Comment: But only in the context of a request, in which case you can either add it as a URL parameter in the AJAX request or reformulate the AJAX request as a post and send it as a form parameter.

Comment: I see what you're saying, however, I'm not sure how much control I have over how the jqGrid reloadGrid I have (which is where I need the flag).  This is my reload code.  How can I pass a value in the URL here?

Comment: $('#ShowClosed').click(function () { $('#jqgWorkOrdersList').trigger('reloadGrid'); });

Comment: Perhaps send the state, persist it server-side, then invoke the reload trigger in the callback: `$('#ShowClosed').click(function () { $.post('/some/url/to/persistcb', $('#checkbox').serialize(), function() { $('#jqgWorkOrdersList').trigger('reloadGrid'); }); });`  You also might be able to tie in to the `beforeRequest` or `loadBeforeSend` event on the jqGrid to set some custom data in the grid.

Comment: I figured out that you can do something along the lines of this:    $('#ShowClosed').click(function () {
   var urlString = '@Url.Action("GetWorkOrders", "WorkOrders")?ShowClosed = $("#ShowClosed").valueOf';
   alert(urlString);
   $("#jqgWorkOrdersList").jqGrid().setGridParam({ url: urlString }).trigger("reloadGrid");
  });  I'm still working on getting my Razor syntax correct, but it seems to work.  This passes in the value of the checkbox to the ajax method.  Your post led me in the right direction though, so thank you very much for that!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use cookie to store this information since it is not any sensitive information.

Take  a look at jQuery cookie plugin [here](http://code.google.com/p/cookies/)

Examples:

```
//A cookie by the name 'checkboxstate' now exists with the value 'true'
$.cookies.set('checkboxstate', 'true'); 

//Variable 'checkBoxState' now holds the value 'true'
var checkBoxState = $.cookies.get( 'checkboxstate' ); 

//The cookie named 'checkboxstate' has been deleted.
$.cookies.del('checkboxstate');
```

There are various ways to persist data on the client or server side out of which `cookie` is one of them. You can take a look at this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300437.aspx, it will definitely help you decide which one to go for based on your requirement.

Comment: Ah, cookies!!  I knew there was another storage container I wasn't thinking of!  I think this will work great, thanks!

Comment: I suppose I could also use the Cache.  That might be a better solution than cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use Sessions?

```
Session["value_name"] = Something.Text;
```

(More about Sessions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87069683(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I'd prefer not to use session as it can timeout and I'd lose the value.

Comment: Without saving the value somewhere... cookie/session/database/file... I don't think you can keep a persistent value in a stateless environment (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Persistent_connections).

Comment: Well, sure, but at least you can set the timeout of a cookie.  Plus there is always the problem of a client that has turned cookies off, but since this is an intranet app, that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @summea - You can set when the cookie should timeout.